# MS CRM An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

I'm currently learning Extending Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online and On Premise Course provided by Microsoft.

I'm simply following the steps according to [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cppdh2qypkt1gt5/L05%20-%20Using%20the%20Organization%20Service.docx?dl=0) lab documentation. The code should be perfectly working but it doesn't work for me.

Connection Strings:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="CRMOnline"
     connectionString=
                 "Url=https://xxxxxx.api.crm5.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc;   
                 Username=xxxxxx@damnits.onmicrosoft.com; 
                 Password=xxxxxx;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

The connection :

```
        CrmConnection con = new CrmConnection("CRMOnline");

        IOrganizationService service = new OrganizationService(con);

        WhoAmIRequest req = new WhoAmIRequest();

        var result = service.Execute(req) as WhoAmIResponse;

        if (result != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Organization ID: {0}\nBusiness Unit ID: {1}\nuser ID:{2}", result.OrganizationId, result.BusinessUnitId, result.UserId));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

The exception is caught in this line :
var result = service.Execute(req) as WhoAmIResponse;
Innerexception said "Invalid Request".

- I have made sure the credentials on connectionStrings are correct multiple times
- I think I have already synchronized the date & time for my pc and the CRM (synchronized internet time & selected the correct time zone on both PC & CRM. Even tested created a record & checked date&time created is correct.)

What else could cause this error?

Thank You.

Comment: instead of "CRMOnline" you wrote the correct connection string, right?

Comment: Can you post your connection string? clear out any sensitive information.

Comment: The name of the connectionString is "CRMOnline". Post edited.

Comment: It seems you are passing CRM's application URL, instead you can try passing Organization service URL in the connection string. It is generally in "https://xxxxxx.api.crm4.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc" format. You can get the exact URL from Settings >> Customizations >> Developer Resources

Comment: Hi @Nirman thanks for your answer. I changed the URL to Organization service URL but the result is still the same.

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully this helps someone else, I was fighting with this same error for a good while today as well.

Turns out I was using an older version of the Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies nuget package(7.1.1 in one project and 8.0.0 in another) as soon as I updated it to the latest (8.2.0.2) I was able to successfully connect to CRM Online.

Answer (score 0):

The error "An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party" usually means that the **password is incorrect**, but it can also occur if the **time between** the application and the CRM server is more than 5 minutes apart. I have seen this happen when an application is deployed to a virtual server and the VM experiences "time drift" - it might work at some point, but the VM may slowly get out of sync with internet time and then run into issues authenticating.

From [this](https://www.crmug.com/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?MessageKey=f6af2094-ed02-4a03-bb9d-ea6f42380d87&CommunityKey=5ab602e5-51fe-4cc2-b467-d970807c0e8a&tab=digestviewer) forum thread

Comment: "...time between the application and the CRM server is more than 5 minutes apart..." was my own problem.